# How should attached files be saved?

Tags: javascript, mysql, linux, filesystems, multer

I am currently doing it like this with [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), but I am not sure what the best practice is.

The files are saved in a `files` folder with the following naming convention: `uid-filename`

ex. `pdMNjRYIJTn9vw84tPCF-some_file_name.jpg`.

The reason for the UID is to allow saving files with the same name. The file is downloaded without the UID in the name.

Is this a good way to do this? What can be improved?

### Table

| id | recordId | originalName | uid | fileName | extension | path | size | userId | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | some_file_name.jpg | pdMNjRYIJTn9vw84tPCF | pdMNjRYIJTn9vw84tPCF-some_file_name.jpg | jpg | /uploads/pdMNjRYIJTn9vw84tPCF-some_file_name.jpg | 76463 | 1 | 2021-04-25 11:53:17 |

### Client

```js
async function uploadFile(file) {
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("recordUid", recordUid);

    let res = await fetchPostFile("/api/files", formData);
}
```

### Server

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: filesFolderPath,
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let uid = generateUid();
        cb(null, `${uid}-${file.originalName}`);
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10 }, // 10 mb
});

router.post("/api/files", upload.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let { recordUid } = req.body;
        let { originalName, filename, path, size } = req.file;

        let parts = originalName.split(".");
        let extension = parts[parts.length - 1];
        let uid = filename.substring(0, 20);

        let query = `
            insert into file
                (
                    recordId, 
                    originalName, 
                    uid, 
                    fileName, 
                    extension, 
                    path, 
                    size, 
                    userId, 
                    created
                )
            values
                (
                    (select id from record where uid = ?), 
                    ?, 
                    ?, 
                    ?, 
                    ?, 
                    ?, 
                    ?, 
                    ?, 
                    now()
                );
        `;

        let rows = await req.asyncQuery(query, [recordUid, originalName, uid, filename, extension, path, size, req.userId]);

        res.status(200).send({ success: true });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } finally {
        req.connection.release();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Original filename should be truncated on disk but saved in DB for reference. Just identify disk files by (U)UID.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by truncated on disk?

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is clean although I personally would not use a 32 bit UUID but instead obfuscate the user's(making the upload) id together with the current timestamp. In short, only the timestamp should do because the incoming files all have different names so it will make sense if they all have the same timestamp. That is more like what you have already but mine (file name) will be shorter. So trying to be conservative a bit.

And you mentioned about not having the uid on the downloaded file. With the approach i explained above, you dont really have to bother about truncating the uuid before serving the file to the client. This is the same convention our devices (phones, laptops, etc) use to save files. Appending Timestamps.

This is just my opinion.

Comment: What do you mean by truncating the uuid?

Comment: Stripping off the uid before sending back to the client.

Comment: This is the second time you asking about truncation so I will assume you dont know what that means. Truncation simply means to shorten in duration or extent according to oxford dictionary.

Comment: I managed to refactor the code so I no longer have the UID in the name. The files are saved on disk with the UID as the name, without an extension. If someone wants to download it, I rename the file and add the extension.